# Tool to tell me the optimal number of threads

Tags: gratis, multi-threading

[This S.O question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828296/how-many-threads-can-i-run-concurrently) is knocking on seven years old already.

It asks what the optimal number of threads is (or was, back in the days when there were no multi-core CPUS).

Is there any app which I can run against my program to benchmark, check & recommend the optimal number of threads (assuming, obviously, that all threads perform the same action)?

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to use a general-purpose benchmarking library for your programming language? What would you want beyond that? Also, which language are you using?

Comment: That sounds like I would have to make repeated builds, with increasing numbers of threads & benchmark them. I am wondering if there is a toll which does this; maybe a plugin for Valgrind

Comment: Right. I think it can be done with a short shell loop like `for nthreads in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ; do make THREADS=$nthreads && echo $nthreads && time ./myprogram ; done`.

Comment: Yes, I could knock up a Python script to do that. But I was wondering if there was an existing tool, maybe with more knowledge than I have, fancy GUI, charts, etc